# A regular expression that defines a language

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-language

I am reading a chapter about regular expressions and there is the following example present in the book :

> Let $\sum =\left \{ 0,1 \right \}$. Find regular expressions over
>   $\sum$ that define the following language.
>
> The language consisting of all strings of 0’s and 1’s that do not
>   contain two consecutive 1’s

Their answer is $\left ( 0\mid 10 \right )^{*}\left ( \epsilon \mid 1 \right )$

I thought that it would be $\left ( 10 \right )^{*}$ . Why is my answer not correct?

Or why $\left ( 0\mid 10 \right )^{*}1$ is not correct either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0 \in L$, but not in your language $(10)^*$.

Further 
$$
(0|10)^*(\epsilon | 1) = (0|10)^* \epsilon  \,|\, (0|10)^* 1 = 
(0|10)^* \,|\, (0|10)^* 1
$$
E.g. $10 \in (0|10)^*$, which is in $L$ but not in your $(0|10)^*1$.

Comment: What about $\left ( 0\mid 10 \right )^{*}1$. This language has 0, 00, 00101...

Comment: All strings that match $(0|10)^*1$ end with a 1

Answer (score 1):

The string "$00$" matches the requirements but your answers doesn't permit that to happen.